# Keycloak - Export realm and user data

Tags: keycloak

We are currently on KeyCloak v8.02 installed as a windows service using Oracle provider and we are going to upgrade to KeyCloak v16 using PostgreSQL. Currently I am trying to export the realm and users data by using the below command.

```
sh standalone.sh \
    -Dkeycloak.migration.action=export \
    -Dkeycloak.migration.provider=singleFile \
    -Dkeycloak.migration.file=keycloak-export.json \
    -Djboss.http.port=8888 -Djboss.https.port=9999 \
    -Djboss.management.http.port=7777
```

We have three realms and the data that is being exported just has the master realm data (not even the master users data). What is happening? How can we export and import the data while migrating to another version?

Comment: I am also currently stuck on this for a Keycloak version 18 installation.